# Logging another person off in Windows 7 using Task Manager

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, task-manager

Under WinXP, I could use Task Manager's Users tab to log off my wife's account which she always leaves logged in so I don't have to log in to her account and log it out.  It's an older machine so I used that trick to free up every resource I could which might potentially slow down the game I'm playing at the time.

I recently upgraded the machine to Win7 and when I try the same trick, I get an access denied popup.  My logged in account does have Admin rights, so is it as simple as runing Task Manager "as an Administrator" in order to allow this?  If so, how can I pull up Task Manager (other than the standard CTRL-ALT-DELETE) to have it pop up with Admin rights in order to log her account off in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to processes and click "Show Processes From All Users". This will elevate your task manager to administrator.